# Negative Number power infinity is not giving correct when Using 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, infinity

Here is the 2 code which should return '-inf' but 2nd is giving only 'inf'. Can any body help me why this is happening

```
>>> -2**float('inf')
```

-inf

```
>>> float(-2)**float('inf')
```

inf

Comment: try `(-2)**float('inf')`...

Comment: Thats not the question, we need to have an explanation why `float(-2)**float('inf')` gives `inf`

Comment: @mishsx then OP should edit the question's content and title to match that.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 `Can any body help me why this is happening...` means you need to explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out Python's [operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the `**` is evaluated before the unary `-`.

so `-2**float('inf')` is `-(2**float('inf'))` which is `-(inf)` which is `-inf`.

`(-2)**float('inf')` is also `inf` just like `float(-2)**float('inf')`

Comment: You are unclear with second part. Also dont forget the parenthesis have a higher precedence. You still don't have an answer

Comment: The usual *convention* is that pow(x, +∞) returns +∞ for |x| > 1. The rationale for that is presumably that any sufficiently large floating-point number represents an *even* integer, and therefore +∞ which is larger than any large finite floating-point number should be treated the same way.